# PTIJ: Why are so many people against BDS?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Numerous (esp. religious English-speaking / yeshivish) people write "BSD" on the top of their correspondences. I've seen this abbreviation on store signs and in ads, and many other places. It means "With Heaven's Providence" - a sign that all that happens in life is because G-d wants it.

Well, we know that the "D" stands for *dishmaya* and is a reference to G-d. Yet, G-d doesn't just reside in heaven; He is everywhere and moves around. So that should mean that it should be no problem to move the reference to G-d around, either and just say or use "BDS", right?

Yet, I'm hearing many Jews in the U.S. say how terrible the "BDS movement" is. They condemn it, and even some politicians have banned and condemned businesses that support the "BDS movement".

I don't understand this. All you're doing is moving a reference to G-d in a mnemonic and, as I mentioned, G-d moves, so why can't a reference to Him move, too? What's so terrible about the BDS movement?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: krovim https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89954/ptij-why-all-the-obsession-with-bsd

Comment: specifically, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89966/16354

Comment: @rosends Not exactly. Though, I did see that Q earlier today.

Comment: Isn’t it obvious? Since Hashem is everywhere, they claim that there’s nothing special about Israel and that we therefore don’t have a claim to it.

Comment: God does not move. See Hilchot Yesodei Torah 1:11. Movement would also be impossible if he was everywhere.

Comment: What does BDS stand for?

Comment: @Daniel Boycott, Divest, Sanction. You can Google it and you'll see loads of info on it, as it' s very much in the news currently.

Comment: @DanF I meant in the context of this question. The B and the S are part of the same word in the original acronym so they can't really be separated. So what does the new acronym stand for?

Answer (score 6):

As you describe, the BDS movement feels that G-d has a specific location, and can therefore be moved from one location to another. "Hashem is here, Hashem is there..." they joyfully sing to themselves.

But this is heretical, as discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1153/4794). Therefore, we should boycott, divest from, and sanction such an acronym.