# PTIJ: What kind of hat does Hashem wear?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

What kind of hat does the Almighty wear? I'm not sure which brand He wears for the 'victory hat' mentioned in  [אַנְעִים זְמִירות](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Shabbat%2C_Musaf_L%27Shabbat%2C_Shir_HaKavod.2?vhe=Daat_Siddur_Ashkenaz&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> חָבַשׁ כּובַע יְשׁוּעָה בְּראשׁו - He dons a hat of salvation on His
> head

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89965/170

Comment: Probably a Borsalino!